# CSS text-overflow depending on space left besides sibling elements

Tags: html, siblings, css

I'm trying to style a list entry consiting of text on the left and action elements on the right.
If the text runs longer then the available space text shall be replaced by an ellipsis.

```
 - This is a list entry with text that is… [>]
```

If you hover the list entry, more action elements will be shown like:

```
 - This is a list entry with text tha… [x] [>]
```

I'd prefer a CSS only solution, not depending on JS.

This is what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/rBthS/265/
but somehow I have the feeling that I'm missing something.

There must be a straighter way. Can you help?

Comment: I think Firefox has some problems with that code: have you seen it there?

Comment: no, just testing in chrome. sorry, could have mentioned that …

Comment: now working in FF as well http://jsfiddle.net/rBthS/265/

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this a bit more the simpler solution I was looking for is this http://jsfiddle.net/rBthS/272/

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="float: right;">Foo Bar</div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">
      More text then this can handle …
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>…</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an xml for FF.
This is the CSS code:

```
white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; -o-text-overflow: ellipsis; -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis; -moz-binding: url('path_to_xml/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
        xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
        xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        >
    <binding id="ellipsis">
        <content>
            <xul:window>
                <xul:description crop="end" xbl:inherits="value=xbl:text"><children/></xul:description>
            </xul:window>
        </content>
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

I've tested on FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE and it works.

There is a whole post [here](http://sharonminsuk.com/blog/2010/07/22/css3-text-truncation-and-ellipses-even-in-firefox-and-without-the-styling-constraints/) about this.

Comment: the article starts with this disclaimer:

"This trick became obsolete when Firefox 4 was released in the first half of 2011"

I'm not sure, but I have the feeling this doesn't answer the question.